# TypeError React-Chartjs After Upgrading to Chart.js v3​

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

Our react site is based on the argon-pro-dashboard framework.
After updating to chart.js@^3.6.0 & react-chartjs-2^4.0.0 we are getting some erros:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

src/variables/charts.js:28
  25 | // Code from: https://codepen.io/jedtrow/full/ygRYgo
  26 | //
  27 | 
> 28 | Chart.elements.Rectangle.prototype.draw = function () {
  29 |   var ctx = this._chart.ctx;
  30 |   var vm = this._view;
  31 |   var left, right, top, bottom, signX, signY, borderSkipped, radius;
```

Does anyone encounter this issue? and know if there is a way to fix it?
Probably because of the version gap we are experiencing this manner.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is a major version upgrade in which are a lot of breaking changes. For all of them please read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html). In your case `elements.Rectangle` doesnt exist anymore. It has been replaced with `elements.bar`